# Activator.CreateInstance(string, string) throwing TypeLoadException

Tags: c#, reflection, activator, typeloadexception

I have the following code:

```
public static void Invoke(string assemblyName, string scheduledTaskExecutorName)
{
    ObjectHandle objectHandle = Activator.CreateInstance(assemblyName, scheduledTaskExecutorName);
    IScheduledTaskExecutor scheduledTaskExecutor = (IScheduledTaskExecutor)objectHandle.Unwrap();
    scheduledTaskExecutor.ExecuteScheduledTask();
}
```

I have a class called `DummyScheduledTaskExecutor` which looks like this:

```
public class DummyScheduledTaskExecutor : IScheduledTaskExecutor
{
    public void ExecuteScheduledTask()
    {
        DummyTextFile.Text = "Success!";
    }
}
```

It resides in an assembly whose assembly name (as defined in the assembly's properties) is `Tests.WebApplication.Application.Unit`.

My call to `Invoke(string, string)` looks like this:

```
ScheduledTaskInvoker.Invoke("Tests.WebApplication.Application.Unit", "DummyScheduledTaskExecutor");
```

Trying to run this code just throws a TypeLoadException. Have I expressed the assembly or type name incorrectly, or is something else going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

scheduledTaskExecutorName need to include the namespace.

Try including the whole namespace in your second parameter.

My example:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication6
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(null, "WindowsFormsApplication6.TestClass");
        }
    }
}

namespace WindowsFormsApplication6
{
    public class TestClass
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Nowhere in the documentation did it state I need to use the namespace. I've now got an IOException, so you've moved me on!

Comment: If you are using a singleton class for file output be sure to use lock(<a static object in your class>) {} as I have had these issues before when creating a logging class.

Comment: Well, even though I said the same thing before you, I guess you were clearer <sniff>.  I'll give you an upvote 'cause I can't stand when people accept an answer but don't upvote it.  What's up with that, @David?

Answer (score 0):

did you try the assembly binding log?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4.aspx

Comment: I just tried now, but it's not listing any assembly bind failures. The code is failing within an MSTest unit test. I don't know if that's relevant.

Answer (score 0):

**CreateInstance** will assume the assembly is already loaded.  My guess is it actually isn't.  You need to use **CreateInstanceFrom** instead.

EDIT: Well if you know the assembly is loaded, then it is most likely a problem with your parameters to CreateInstance.  Use the fully qualified type name instead of the simple class name like you are now.

Comment: It's the current assembly. I assume this means it's loaded?